# My Java JDK doesn't seem to have javadoc

Tags: javadoc, java

I'm using Eclipse on Linux Mint and can't find the javadoc command line tool. I have a JDK and JRE installed:
[image: screen1]

According to other SO questions and different forums I found through Google, javadoc should be in one of these places:
[image]
[image]

Well, it isn't there. I did a search for "javadoc" in the whole filesystem, and it did only come up with some documentation in /usr/share/doc. So I'm convinced that I indeed don't have javadoc on my system, but as far as I can see, the JDK should have it included. Every thread/SO question I can find states that... Any ideas of what I could do?

A search in the repositories has also shown that there is no javadoc package I might be missing. There's the openjdk-[6|7]-doc packages, but those contain documentation, and not the javadoc tool.

Comment: I'm new to OpenJDK, did you ever find the location where the javadocs are suppose to be? I'm using 1.8

Comment: Ya ever find the location? I am using OpenJDK 11, but I have no declaration or JavaDoc in Eclipse.